# What are the OS X session types, and what do they mean?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, launchd

I've been trying to find out the meaning of LimitLoadToSessionType in launchctl on OS X (Lion).

After scouring the internet, it seems the value can be one of:
Aqua, LoginWindow, Background, StandardIO and System.

Are there any missing, and more importantly, does anyone know what effect they have?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This Apple Technical Note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html) explains most of the session types (it doesn't cover System; I think Tech Note was last updated for Snow Leopard and System was probably added for Lion):

Briefly:

- Aqua: a GUI agent; has access to all the GUI services
- LoginWindow: pre-login agent; runs in the login window context
- Background: runs in the parent context of the user
- StandardIO: runs only in non-GUI login session (e.g. SSH sessions)

I could guess about System, but then so could you. I wish Apple would update the TN2083 for OS X 10.7.

Comment: I don't understand what System is either but I ran across a command line app that required it and it means you must install under root. For example with brew, you would do "sudo brew services start <formula>" and then the "System" LimitLoadToSessionType is available (its not under a user agent)